# How to show border lines on tree table view using JavaFX with CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX with CSS.
And I want to show the border line of the header.
This is the default situation:
[tree table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSAil.png)

And the following picture is what I am excepting for:
[What I except for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sscJF.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
.tree-table-view .column-header,
.tree-table-view .column-header .filler,
.tree-table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: #d9e4f1;
    -fx-border-width: 0.1px;
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff,-fx-table-cell-border-color;
}
```

This worked.